# How operating system links events with dom object?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, operating-system, event-loop

When we click mouse ,it send signal to operating system and through this way OS can identify which resource is affected and run event handler.

How does this mouse click is mapped to our click event on dom object?
how OS attach our event handler to the dom tree objects and executes it in event loop?

/*Editted*/

I asked this question for specific hardware resource.Would it be same for internal resources eg: when we say nodejs server listens for request event and executes event handler.Here Nodejs is runs on operating system and http server is setup by nodejs(ip + port)..so in this case which resource is Listening for incoming request ?

Comment: This is not an issue.I want to understand the concept of event handling .

Comment: _When we click mouse ,it send signal to operating system_ Not exactly. Most of things are handled by JS `runtime` and browser `webAPIs`

Comment: @FZs - The question is clear without code (in fact, I don't see how code would make it clearer).

Answer (score 4):

The *operating system* doesn't. The event goes through a series of layers. Each layer knows more detail about that specific layer than the previous one:

- The mouse handler (in the OS) relays a click at X,Y on the screen to the window manager (also often part of the OS, but swappable on various *nix variants)
- The window manager relays the click to the application for the window the click occurred in
- The application in the window (in this case, a web browser) relays the click to your event handler

Since the browser knows the DOM, and knows which DOM element was clicked, it can check for event handlers on that element and call those handlers with the correct element.

Each layer has only the details specific to that layer. The mouse handler knows what kind of mouse it's dealing with, but the window manager and browser (probably) don't. *(They can ask the OS if they want to know, but usually don't have to.)* The mouse handler doesn't know where the windows are (or even that there *are* windows), but the window manager does. The window manager doesn't know about the DOM elements (and various other parts of the browser like its bookmarks bar or similar) are, but the browser does.

*(The above is just a very rough sketch, there are more layers involved, but it gives you the idea.)*

Comment: thanks, This is helpful to visualize the flow.I asked this question for specific hardware resource.Would it be same for internal resources eg: when we say nodejs server listens for request event and executes event handler.Here Nodejs is runs on operating system and http server is setup by nodejs(ip + port)..so in this case which resource is listens for incoming request ?

Comment: @SurajPrakashJoshi - The OS's network stack does. The OS offers system calls to interact with the network. Node.js uses those system calls to implement its API. Your code uses Node.js's API to implement your server. Layers again. :-)

Comment: It's the same for nearly everything on a modern computer: Video display, audio input/output, etc. There are layers, where each layer knows enough to do its job for the other layers.